# PHP Calculator: My solutions won't show up I click calculate

Tags: php, html

I've recently started the assignment of building a calculator out of PHP and I can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong in my code. Every time I press calculate it doesn't give me back my solution.

```
<?php

$num1 = $_GET['num1'];
$num2 = $_GET['num2'];
$cal = $_GET['opt'];

if($num2, $num2 != (int)){
    $num1=0;
    $num2=0;
}


    switch($cal) {

        case 'add':
        echo $num1+$num2;
        break;

        case 'sub':
        echo $num1-$num2;
        break;

        case 'mul':
        echo $num1*$num2;
        break;

        case 'div':
        echo $num1/$num2;
        break;

        default:
        echo "Invalid Operator";
    }



?>
```

Here is the HTML

```
<form action="calculate.php" method="GET"/>

Number 1:<input type="text" name="num1"/>
<br />
<select>
<option type="text" name="opt" value="add"> + </option>
<option type="text" name="opt" value="sub"> - </option>
<option type="text" name="opt" value="mul"> * </option>
<option type="text" name="opt" value="div"> / </option>
</select>

<br />
Number 2:<input type="text" name="num2"/>
<br />

<input type="submit" value="calculate"/>




</form>
```

Comment: The question was downvoted probably for the reason it was closed: it's too "localized" which means you're asking a very general question ("why doesn't this work?") about a very specific project (yours).It's better to ask very specific questions about very general problems.  That way it's easier to answer, and will likely be useful to people with the same problem later.

Don't be too discouraged!  :-) It's your first question, and you got burned.  You asked why on meta, so I can see you're willing to improve future questions.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
$num1 = intval($_GET['num1']);
$num2 = intval($_GET['num2']);
```

and remove

```
if($num2, $num2 != (int)){
  $num1=0;
  $num2=0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`if($num2, $num2 != (int))` looks like a syntax error to me (the comma).

You just say it doesn't work, are you getting an error message? Have you made sure error reporting is on and displaying errors to your browser? I think it should tell you about the syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

I would initialise the var differently:

```
<?php

$num1 = $num2 = 0;
if (isset($_GET['num1']) && isset($_GET['num1']) && isset($_GET['num1']))
{
  $num1 = $_GET['num1'];  
  $num2 = $_GET['num2'];
  // edit: added validation
  if (!is_numeric($num1) || !is_numeric($num2))
  {
    $res = NULL;
  }
  else
  {
  $cal = $_GET['opt'];
  switch($cal)
  {
    case 'add':
      $res = $num1+$num2;
    break;
    case 'sub':
      $res = $num1-$num2;
    break;
    case 'mul':
      $res = $num1*$num2;
    break;
    case 'div':
      $res = $num1/$num2;
    break;
    default:
      $res = NULL;
  }
  }
}
// display html on the same file
?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="calculate.php" method="GET"/>
  Number 1:<input type="text" name="num1"/>
  <br />
  <select>
    <option type="text" name="opt" value="add"> + </option>
    <option type="text" name="opt" value="sub"> - </option>
    <option type="text" name="opt" value="mul"> * </option>
    <option type="text" name="opt" value="div"> / </option>
  </select>
  <br />
  Number 2:<input type="text" name="num2"/>
  <br />
  <input type="submit" value="calculate"/>
</form>
<? if (isset($res) && $res != NULL): ?>
  <span class="result-label">Result:</span> <span class="result"><?=$res?></span>
<? endif ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you guys! You where very helpful.. but why was an question down voted? I thought my concerns were legitimate..

Comment: @Uboonto: Is there are reason you call `isset` on `$_GET['num1']` three times in a row? Copy-paste error?

Comment: yeah sorry, copy paste error - it should test $_GET['num1'], $_GET['num2'], $_GET['opt'] - thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score -1):

This is wrong

```
if($num2, $num2 != (int)){
  $num1=0;
  $num2=0;
}
```

try

```
$num1 = intval( $num1 );
$num2 = intval( $num2 );
```